# Add a .ics file from my app to iOS Calendar

Tags: ios, objective-c, calendar

I have a calendar (`.ics` file). I want to create a button that when clicked, opens the `iCal` file in `iOS Calendar` and asks if you want to add it to your `iOS Calendar` (like on some websites on the internet: http://icaltv.com/calendars/all-tv-shows/) 
Is that possible?

I tried to open it with `UIDocumentInteractionController` but that did not work.

Thank you for advance.

**EDIT:**

The provisional solution that I found is:

```
NSString *url = @"webcal://url.ics";
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
```

Comment: You should post your provisional solution as an answer.